# Locked with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am locked with Android Studio.

As I was developing my first android app, I sometime pushed the "Run 'app'" button to test and see how the app was working. With no problem up to this point, but then I tried to use Image Asset Studio to make my own icon. And now when I try to use the "Run 'app'" button to test, all I can see is the image below keeping coming back and the app is no longer started. I guess I did something wrong on the way; though I have no idea what. Can anyone think of what I should do to get back on my feet and have the app working again? I haven't changed any part of the code since it was last working.

[image]

And hereafter is a second screenshot showing an error:

[image]

Running the find command on the project directory, for the file *ic_launcher.webp*, I get this result.
I suppose some of the files shouldn't be there.

```
MyMac$ find AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp -name ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.webp
MyMac$
```

But for comparison if I run the same command on the directory for a project where this issue does not appear. I find even more of the *ic_launcher.webp* file, so I must be missing some detail.

```
MyMac$ find AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp -name ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.webp
AndroidStudioProjects/MyOtherApp/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.webp
MyMac$
```

Comment: Does Studio show you any error in Build tab?

Comment: Indeed I have errors in the Buid tab. A list of Duplicate resources messages, that I partly showed in a second screenshot that I just added to my post.

Comment: In the Project panel, does studio list these duplicate files?

Comment: Yes I saw the duplicate files. I started by removing some files.
Then I was finally able to fall back on my feet.
I built the launch icon again, being more careful while using Image Asset Studio.
I followed this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-update-the-launcher-icon-for-your-android-app--cms-30624.
Now all is correct.

Comment: It's good,  then.